# Error when scheduling code later

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks, apscheduler

I have a problem with APSchedule library. I want to run specific code at specific day. I created the next code, but i get an error. I tried different methods(you can see the code), but i get the same error.

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import date

def some_job():
    print ("Decorated job")

scheduler = BlockingScheduler()
#scheduler.add_job(some_job(), 'date', run_date='2017-10-03 15:58:55', args=['text'])
#scheduler.add_job(some_job(), 'date', run_date=datetime(2017, 10, 3, 15, 58, 55), args=['text'])
scheduler.add_job(some_job(), args=['text'])
scheduler.start()
```

**Error :**
Decorated job
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Alexey/Education/Courses/Selenium WebDriver with Python/SeleniumDriversTests/Scheduler.py", line 12, in 
    scheduler.add_job(some_job(), args=['text'])
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\apscheduler\schedulers\base.py", line 425, in add_job
    job = Job(self, **job_kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\apscheduler\job.py", line 44, in **init**
    self._modify(id=id or uuid4().hex, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\apscheduler\job.py", line 165, in _modify
    raise TypeError('func must be a callable or a textual reference to one')
TypeError: func must be a callable or a textual reference to one

Comment: You're calling some_job() and passing its return value (None) to scheduler.add_job(). That's why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because add_job wants a function as param so that scheduler will run it runtime.So remove the brackets after some_job and also some_job has no function params so you need to delete the args or add a param to some_job method

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import date

def some_job(name):
    print ("Decorated job "+name)

scheduler = BlockingScheduler()
scheduler.add_job(some_job, args=['text'])
scheduler.start()
```